# Boost condition timed_wait causing memory-leaks

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, memory-leaks, boost-thread

I am getting a weird memory-leak issue. In the following code, `blockCondition` is `boost::condition` where lock is defined as `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(blockingMutex)`, where `blockingMutex` is an `boost::mutex`.

```
boost::xtime xt;
boost::xtime_get(&xt, 1);
xt.sec += 10;
if(!blockCondition.timed_wait(lock, xt))
{
    xt.sec += 5;
}
```

Specifically, the line `if(!blockCondition.timed_wait(lock, xt))` uses up some extra memory, I have no clue why!

Is there any issues in how this code is being used that could give memory-leaks. I am using the Boost with version 1.47.0. Please help!

Comment: How did you detect that it is a memory leak?

Comment: In my program, I am calling this part of code large number of times, and I detected the memory being allocated in the task manager, exploding and the program crashes. If I call it a lesser number of times, the memory allocation still explodes, but it does not crash. So, I concluded my program crashes because of this part as when I commented this part out, the memory explosion doesn't occur!

Comment: Then show us this part of code

Comment: I wish I could show the complete part, but I'm afraid its not a small piece of code. I just needed to ask, if the use of timed_wait is correct as I have shown in the question.

Comment: Using is correct. Problem is not in this part of code i guess.

Comment: Where do you create the mutex?  Continually created/used/destroyed - OK-ish.  Created once/used/never destroyed fine.  Continually created, never destroyed...